# Pytorch: convolution with non-constant kernel

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, convolution

Is there a built-in function in any torch-compatible library that allows to consider convolutions (in 2 dimensions) with kernels that depend on the coordinates of the input.

More precisely, I would like a function such that:

- the input has size (C_in,H,W),
- kernel has size (C_in,C_out,H,W,K,K) (while usually it has size (C_in,C_out,K,K)),
- the output has size (C_out,H,W),
- C_in and C_out are the numbers of channels of the input and the output respectively,
- H is the height,
- W is the width,
- K is the size of the kernel (in each of the two directions).

This can also be viewed as a sparse fully connected layer.

For those who know a bit about mathematics, this corresponds to integrating against a kernel with no translation invariance, i.e.

```
output(x,y)=\integral k(x,y)*input(y) dy
```

while the usual convolution in torch is:

```
output(x,y)=\integral k(x - y)*input(y) dy.
```

I implemented it twice by myself, once using torch.sparse, and once using multiple convolutions. It works but it is so much longer than a usual convolution while the number of basic arithmetic operations is the same (which means that it should take about the same computational time as a convolution).

Comment: Isn't your kernel supposed to have a size of `(C_in, C_out, H//K, W//K, K, K)`?

Comment: I do not think so: for any h in [1,H] and w in [1,W], I need a (K,K) tensor to create the output at coordinates (h,w).